# Why is there white spaces when the button is pressed for my tkinter python clock

Tags: python, tkinter, clock

This is a clock that i just recently started, what i want to do is for the button to have each functions such as alarm and clock. I have done that but when i press the button white spaces would come out and the title would shift to the right and have a little indentation. and overall the design is just too weird as i just got on to tkinter i haven't learn much about frames.

```
import time
import tkinter as tk

#Initialise the window
clock = tk.Tk()
clock.title('Easy CLock')
clock.geometry('400x700')
clock.configure(bg='#121212')

border_effects = {
    "flat": tk.FLAT,
    "sunken": tk.SUNKEN,
    "raised": tk.RAISED,
    "groove": tk.GROOVE,
    "ridge": tk.RIDGE,
}

#Time and Date function
def time_date():
    # current time
    current_time = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    current_date = time.strftime(r'%m/%d/%Y')
    clock.after(200, time_date)
    #Displays the time
    c_time = tk.Label(f_time, text = current_time, fg='white', bg='#121212', font=('Verdana', 30))
    c_date = tk.Label(f_time, text = current_date, font=('Verdana', 10), fg='white', bg='#121212')
    c_time.grid(column=0, row=1)
    c_date.grid(column=0, row=2)

#alarm button command
def alarm_func():
    c_clicked = tk.Label(text='Alarm Interface', fg='white', bg='#121212')
    c_clicked.grid(column=0, row=1)


#Creating Frames
f_header = tk.Frame(clock) #Header
f_time = tk.Frame(clock)  #Clock Button
f_alarm = tk.Frame(clock) #Alarm Buttton
f_exit = tk.Frame(clock) #Exit button

#Setting the Frames with grid
f_header.grid(column=0 , row=0, columnspan = 3)
f_time.grid(column=0, row =3)
f_alarm.grid(column=1, row=3)
f_exit.grid(column=2, row =3)

#Setting label in the frame
f_lbl = tk.Label(f_header, text='Simplistic Clock', font=('Verdana', 30),fg='white', bg='#121212') # Purple text
time_but = tk.Button(f_time, text='Clock', command= time_date, bg='#f39c12', width = 15, relief = border_effects['ridge'])
alarm_but = tk.Button(f_alarm, text = 'Alarm', command = alarm_func, bg='#f39c12', width = 15, relief = border_effects['ridge'])
quit_but = tk.Button(f_exit, text='Exit', command = clock.quit, bg='#f39c12', width = 15, relief = border_effects['ridge'])



#Putting it on the frames
f_lbl.grid()
time_but.grid()
alarm_but.grid()
quit_but.grid()


clock.mainloop()
```

also, i want to hide the clock if the alarm button is pressed for example, if the user press the clock button first it will display the code , but when the user decide to press the alarm button i want the clock frame to be hided. i tired user .grid_forget() but it does't work for me. i am not sure about how the frames and gird work.

does the frame has its own column and grid as in each frame the starting would be column = 0, row = 0 or does it follow the parent window.

Comment: First the parent of `c_time` and `c_date` should be `clock`, not `f_time`.  Second you should create the two labels once at program start, then update their text inside `time_date()` function.  Third add `columnspan=3` to `c_time.grid(...)` and `c_date.grid(...)`.

Comment: why should the c_time and c_date be under clock, bcz i would want to forget the f_time frame which consist of the current time and date when the alarm button is press. isnt it easier to make a frame for the time itself. forexample, f_time.grid_forget?

Comment: It is because `f_time` contains the `Clock` button (`time_but`), if you call `f_time.grid_forget()`, it will remove the button as well.  You should create another frame for the `c_time` and `c_date` to do what you want.

Comment: what if i put thr buttons under the main parent clock , and only the time and date under the f_time. So when i call forget it will forget the label n9t the button.

Comment: Actually the three buttons can be under main parent clock.

Comment: that is what i am currently doing, just i still cant call the forget function . I am not sure why. Do i forget the frame itself or forget the label within that frame